# How do I make a while loop break after one of two conditions is fulfilled?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I'm making a simple turn-based fighting game in Python 3. My while loop won't finish when the health of the computer is 0 or below.

I couldn't find any posts answering my problem.
I have tried some different kinds of conditions but it either stops before the loop or doesn't stop.

```
from random import randint

def punch():
    return randint(18, 25)

c_health = 100
p_health = 100


while(c_health and p_health > 0):

    move = input("Pick a move (punch, kick or heal): ").lower()

    if move == "punch":
        damage = punch()
        c_health = c_health - damage
        print(f"You have dealt {damage} dmg.")
        print(f"The computer has {c_health} health.")


    elif move == "kick":
        print(kick())

    elif move == "heal":
        print(heal())
```

I expect the while loop to finish when the c_health reaches 0 or below.

Comment: You need `c_health > 0 and p_health > 0`

Comment: `while(c_health > 0 and p_health > 0):`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
while(c_health > 0 and p_health > 0):
```

Comment: FYI, parentheses around most boolean expressions generally aren't needed in Python. i.e. `while c_health > 0 and p_health > 0:` would work just as well.